# Is the worst case scenario for the time complexity of this quicksort implementation O(n log n)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, quicksort

I want to say its worst time complexity is still n log n. Just because I'm using the middle element as a pivot and so even if the array is already sorted, it will still half the array when it returns from the partitioning  method. I could be wrong though, my DS isn't the best

```
 public static void quicksort(int [] arr, int low, int high){
      if(low < high){
          int pivot = partition(arr, low, high);
          quicksort(arr, low, pivot);
          quicksort(arr, pivot+1, high);
        }
    }

 public static int partition(int [] arr, int low, int high){
     
        int i = low; 
        int j = high;
        int mid = low + (high-low)/2;
        int pivot = arr[mid];
       
        while(true){
           while(arr[i] < pivot){
               i++;
           }
           while(arr[j] > pivot){
               j--;
           } 
            

        if( i >= j) return j;
            
        swap(arr, i, j);
        i++;
        j--;  
         
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hint: What happens if the pivot is always the largest (or smallest) element?

Comment: Worst case is O(n^2).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Worst-case_analysis

Comment: @MitchelPaulin I see what you mean. Thanks again!

Comment: You can avoid that by selecting the pivot to be the median of three between the first,mid and last

Comment: @HikmatFarhat That approach reduces the likelihood of getting bad behavior, but doesn’t guarantee it. See the paper I’ve linked for an example or an input to such a quicksort approach that takes quadratic time to run.

Answer (score 2):

The paper [“A Killer Adversary for Quicksort”](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Edoug/mdmspe.pdf) gives an algorithm that, for any quicksort implementation that satisfies certain “reasonable” requirements and runs deterministically, produces arbitrarily long input sequences that cause the algorithm to run in quadratic time. So while you’re correct that using the middle value as the pivot will prevent your algorithm from running in quadratic time on an already-sorted array, the fact that the pivots are picked deterministically means that there will be some input to the algorithm that causes the performance to degrade, and the linked paper can be used to construct such a pathological input.

Comment: Was this for me? By the way thx for the paper. very interesting

Comment: This was also meant as an answer to the question, since it shows that any simple deterministic quicksort pivot choosing scheme can be defeated.

Answer (score 0):

the worst case of quick sort is when each time the pivot is chosen it's the max or min number/value in the array.
in this case it will run at O(n^2) for the regular version of Quick sort.
However, there's a version of Quick sort that uses the partition algorithm in order to choose better pivots. In this version of Quick sort the worst case is O(nlogn).